# GeoPoint with Spring Data ElasticSearch is giving error : QueryParsingException[field [location] is not a geo_point field]

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, geopoints

I have elasticsearch entity in spring as below :

```
@Document(indexName = "cities_in", type = "cities")
public class CityDocument {

@Id
private String id;

@Field(type = FieldType.String)
private String city;

@Field(type = FieldType.Object)
@GeoPointField
private GeoPoint location;
}
```

but when I see mapping using curl `curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/cities_in/cities/_mapping?pretty=1'` I get output as:

```
  {
   "cities_in" : {
   "mappings" : {
    "cities" : {
      "properties" : {
        "city" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "id" : {
         "type" : "string"
      },
      "location" : {
        "properties" : {
          "geohash" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "lat" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "lon" : {
            "type" : "double"
          }
        }
        }
        }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

and when hit I query I get below error:

```
{
 "error" : {
"root_cause" : [ {
  "type" : "query_parsing_exception",
  "reason" : "No query registered for [geo_point]",
  "index" : "cities_in",
  "line" : 1,
  "col" : 33
} ],
"type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
"reason" : "all shards failed",
"phase" : "query",
"grouped" : true,
"failed_shards" : [ {
  "shard" : 0,
  "index" : "cities_in",
  "node" : "4jGBH3m4SkqNnBwC196hTw",
  "reason" : {
    "type" : "query_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "No query registered for [geo_point]",
    "index" : "cities_in",
    "line" : 1,
    "col" : 33
  }
} ]
  },
  "status" : 400
 }
```

Why is location type not `geo_point`?
How to manage geopoint with spring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Spring, make sure thath you use GeoPoint from spring

**org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint**

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `FieldType.Object` fields get processed before `@GeoPointField` by Spring Data's [`MapperBuilder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/b2f0300856cb3dd9bfeade3e1db26da96bc2d88a/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/MappingBuilder.java).

So you simply need to remove the `@Field(type = FieldType.Object)` annotation and just declare your `location` field like this:

```
@GeoPointField
private GeoPoint location;
```

Comment: Still its working as spring is not creating field type "geo_point". If i am adding mapping using curl and then adding/fetching data from spring its working. May be spring not supporting field type "geo_point"

Comment: What version of Spring Data are you using? Have you deleted the index prior to restarting your Spring app?

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working now. I was using GeoPoint class "org.elasticsearch.common.geo.GeoPoint" instead of "org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint".

Comment: @Val can you tell in what case I must use FieldType.Object? Example, I have an Object Client with name and id attributes, I want to store this in elasticsearch just they way it is (with those 2 attributes), but when I run my app I get an error: 
'MapperParsingException[object mapping for [cliente] tried to parse field [cliente] as object, but found a concrete value]'

Comment: @franzisk This is because your field `cliente` already exists in the mapping and has another type. You cannot change the type once created, you need to create a new index with the correct type for `cliente` and then reindex your data